# How to create an array of audio files in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, audio

Can anyone tell me how to create an array of links to audio files in JavaScript, without using HTML5 Audio tag? I have a function in my HTML that launches on a user's click. This single function launches everything from within JavaScript, so I don't want to use HTML5 Audio.

HTML5:

```
<div id="boxa" onclick="interactBoxA(this)"></div>
```

Inside this function I can trigger random background images to appear in the div, which are selected from an array:

JS:

```
var images = ["url(images/pig.png)", "url(images/cat.png)", "url(images/frog.png)", "url(images/dog.png)"];
```

Can I do this with audio files? After searching on this forum I've tried creating a new audio object with like this:

```
var audio = [];
audio[0] = new Audio();
audio[0].src = "audio/pig.mp3";
audio[1] = new Audio();
audio[1].src = "audio/cat.mp3";
audio[2] = new Audio();
audio[2].src = "audio/frog.mp3";
audio[3] = new Audio();
audio[3] = "audio/dog.mp3";
```

I'd like this to look more like the images array from earlier. Then I can trigger playback based on the index of the array using an if/else statement like this (This is wrong syntax, but just so you get the idea):

```
if (images[0]) {

  audio[0].play();

} else if (images[1]) {

  audio[1].play();

} ... etc...
```

By the way I am new to programming/JS so let me know if what I'm trying to do is more complex than I am trying to do here.

Comment: Have you tried `[new Audio("a.mp3"), new Audio("b.mp3"), new Audio("c.mp3")]`?

Comment: @AluanHaddad No, but I will try this. To be honest, this is what I thought of doing. Don't I have to write the `src =` as well?

Comment: No, `src` is set from the constructor. I just tried that to confirm. That is what I suggest you do. Try things out. You're doing fine, don't be afraid to experiment.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement. As well as finding the solution, I'd like to make sure I understand the code as well. Not dealt with constructors yet. Will have a read up on those.

Comment: Awesome, works 100%, cheers.